# An IntegrityError happened in django1.9

Tags: python, django

I'm pretty new in django 1.9, and I am trying to make an app, but I came across this error, I don't know how to fix it. Here is my error and codes.
error:

```
IntegrityError at /blogapp//post/

NOT NULL constraint failed: blogapp_blog.user_id
```

in models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Blog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=99999)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

in views.py:

```
def post(request):
    form = BlogText()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BlogText(request.POST.copy())
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            title = data['title']
            content = data['content']
            if not Blog.objects.all().filter(title=title):
                blog = Blog.objects.create(title=title,content=content,date=timezone.now())
                return render(request,'blogapp/postok.html')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('The title is used')
    else:
        form = BlogText()
    return render(request,'blogapp/post.html',{'form':form})
```

Do I need to add this in `views.py`?:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
```

Someone Please help me out. I think I am really bad at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because the `user_id` cannot be null:

> NOT NULL constraint failed: blogapp_blog.user_id

You also need to add the `user`:

```
blog = Blog.objects.create(title=title, content=content,
                           date=timezone.now(), user=request.user)
```

Please also make sure that only `logged-in` users are able to access this view by using [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) decorator:

```
@login_required
def post(request):
    # your stuff here
```

Comment: _If the user isn’t currently logged in, user will be set to an instance of AnonymousUser_ .. from [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user)

Comment: Yes,the decorator works, but the users can see each other's article. Actually that's not what I want to achieve.